# Excel add in events stop firing after opening a new sheet

Tags: c#, excel, events

I am developping an excel add in. When my ribbon loads, I add a cell context menu with a button in it. I attach a handler to the click event of the button to select a file. It works fine with the default first sheet when I run excel. However, if I open a new sheet, nothing happens when I click. Why?

My ribbon load function:

```
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.SetVar(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, Globals.Factory);
    }
```

I have several add in that reference a toolbox dll. So here is the setVar function in my public static Helper class of the Toolbox dll:

```
    public static void SetVar(Excel.Application appSource, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactory FactorySource)
    {
        if(path=="")
        {
            string fullPath = typeof(Helper).Assembly.CodeBase;
            string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
            path = new Uri(theDirectory).LocalPath;
        }
        if (app == null)
            app = appSource;
        if (Factory == null)
            Factory = FactorySource;
        rightClickMenu();
    }
```

It calls rightClickMenu which is:

```
    public static void rightClickMenu()
    {
        bool val = false;
        removeRightClickMenu(ref val);
        Office.CommandBarPopup ctrl = (Office.CommandBarPopup)app.CommandBars["Cell"].Controls.Add(Type: Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Before: 1);
        ctrl.Caption = "Perso";
        Office.CommandBarButton btn = (Office.CommandBarButton)ctrl.Controls.Add(Type: Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
        btn.Caption = "Sélectionner un fichier";
        btn.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(selectFile);
    }
```

And the click handler is:

```
    public static void selectFile(Office.CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            //var filename = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
            app.ActiveCell.Value = filename;
        }
    }
```